# EXTJS XML mapping

Tags: xml, extjs4.1

I want to read this XML with using a Ext.data.Model into a ExtJS Store:

```
<interfaces>
    <green> 
        <name>Eth0</name>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
    </green>

    <red>
        <name>Eth1</name>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
    </red>
</interfaces>
```

I want to show 'Eth0' and 'Eth1' in the 'name' column of my interfaces grid.

this mapping  {name: 'interface', mapping: 'green> name'} only shows Eth0.

how can i do a mapping to show Eth0 and Eth1 in the grid?
I should not modify xml file structure.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `record` config of the `XmlReader` is a selector specified relative to the `root` tag.

To read all child tags of the root as a record, regardless of the name of the tag, we can select all child tags using the `> *` selector.

```
Ext.define('MyModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [ 'name', 'enabled' ],
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        reader: {
            type: 'xml',
            root: 'interfaces',
            record: '> *'
        }
    }
});
```

- [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/msjj9/)

Comment: No problem! I've been looking for an excuse to dig into the XML reader since I usually work with JSON.